# Javascript Change text when button is clicked

Tags: javascript

Hi i want to change the text inside a div when the button is click.

```
<div>
    <p id="part1">Hello</p>

    <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Next</button>
</div>



<script>
function myFunction() {
document.getElementById("part1").innerHTML="WORLD";
}
</script>
```

This works perfectly. I have a div that has a text and a button inside, in this case it has the word "Hello". With the code i have when i click the button the word "hello" change to the word "WORLD". I want to make something like a sequence to change the word from "hello" to "world", from "world" to "welcome" and from "welcome" to "my program" (example). and all that with clicking the button multiple times.

Comment: And how do you want to determine what text to use when clicked?

Comment: i also want to know how to do that!

Comment: your requirement is not clear, tell us what do you want to do

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for this `text change cycle` to happen try this:-

```
var textArray=['World', 'My', 'Welcome', 'Something','Hello']
function myFunction() {
    var value = textArray.shift(); //Get the first item from the array
    textArray.push(value); //Push it back for the cycle to repeat.
    document.getElementById("part1").innerHTML=value;
}
```

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J25fp/)

Comment: This is an interesting way of rotating elements. Here might not be the case, but if I don't have to, I wouldn't touch the data source.

Answer (score 0):

Put this into the script tag

```
var curNum=0;
var arrOfDialogs=['hello','welcome to my program','goodbye']
function myFunciton(){
    if(curNum<arrOfDialogs.length)
        document.getElementById('part1').innerHTML=arrOfDialogs[curNum++];
}
```

I understand the other answer also works but this is shorter and simpler.

Answer (score 0):

You can make an array with the names.

Eg:

1st way:[with a counter variable]

```
var namesArr = new Array('hello','world','welcome','welcome to my program');
var counter=0;

document.getElementById("part1").innerHTML=namesArr[counter];
counter++;
```

2nd way :[withOut a counter variable]

```
// Note : Array elements in reverse order

var var namesArr = new Array('welcome to my program','welcome','world','hello');

document.getElementById("part1").innerHTML=namesArr.pop();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this example:

http://jsfiddle.net/6udus/

I do not think it can get simpler than this :)

```
var textArray=['World', 'My', 'Welcome', 'Something','Hello']
var i=0;
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("part1").innerHTML = 
    textArray[i++ % textArray.length]  ;
}
```